# TGraphicControl descendant drawing blank before paint event

Tags: delphi, components, vcl

Created my own simple component based on a TGraphicControl that draws an SVG graphic. The overridden Paint routine is simple...

```
procedure TLFSVGControl.Paint;
begin
  Canvas.Brush.Style := bsClear;
  var g := TGPGraphics.Create(Canvas.Handle);
  g.SetTextRenderingHint(TextRenderingHintClearTypeGridFit);
  g.SetSmoothingMode(SmoothingModeAntiAlias);
  DrawSVG(g);
  DrawTextLabel(g);
  g.Free;
end;
```

Using this component in my application I allow the user to click and drag the component to move it. The problem is that before it gets to the Paint routine its drawing a black (background) box of the component rectangle. The result being that you get a flicker of this black border as the control moves.
As a TGraphicControl cant receive the WM_ERASEBKGND message I am not sure how to work around this.

In the first image below you see the 4 instances of my component drawn correctly and in the 2nd is a screen capture when stopped on a break point at the first line of the Paint method when the user has tried to move the component labeled 2 (runtime). Continuing the application results in the control drawing correctly but I really would like to get rid of this flicker.

FYI. The bounding box of the component is larger than the graphic because this needs to support rotation without clipping the graphic.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Set DoubleBuffered on the parent.

Comment: First thing I tried  Didn't work.

Comment: Try to draw on an offscreen bitmap and draw it to the canvas instead of drawing directly to the control canvas. other than that I think this Q is missing  MCVE to reproduce.

Comment: The `TWinControl` parent draws itself first, background and all, then it requests its `TGraphicControl` children to draw themselves, background and all, inside of their `Paint()` methods. So if you have put a breakpoint in your `Paint()` method, you are seeing what the parent and earlier `TGraphicControl` children have drawn first. It is hard to diagnose flickering issues when you are stopping painting operations mid-action

Comment: That makes sense - thanks. The flicker I am seeing is the black frame around my control as it moves with the mouse. I guess this is a synchronization issue where I want to stop the redraw of the parent while I process the mouse move event and then tell everything to redraw itself. I am working on a different approach now - I will use the mouse move events to update a background data object and then use a timer to redraw/re-position everything based on the background data. Will see if that looks smoother.